# Lightning's tendency to find a tall point on the ground

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, atmospheric-science, causality, lightning

Is lightning's tendency to connect to a high point on the ground due to probability in the colloquial sense, or is there some sort of electromagnetic stream of "information" exchanged between the sky and the ground preceding a lightning strike? In other words, how does lightning "know" to find a high point on the ground?

Comment: For a good explanation, check out this: https://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/estatics/Lesson-4/Lightning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stuff on the ground communicates with sky via the built up static electric charges. The building charge in the cloud will induce a charge in all things nearby. You can see during a thunder storm that your hair stands up if you are really close to lightning (this also means it's about to strike and you should take cover). The same thing happens with leaves on trees and all structures. Often a leaf will float up and a small discharge will occur between the leaf and the cloud. This discharge then creates a spot where the plasma from the lightning becomes conductive and shoots from the leaf to a spot on the ground, usually from the spot where something went up.

In general this is a property of electricity trying to take the path of least resistance to the ground. The plasma that creates lightning conduct electricity very well but before the plasma is created air is a very good insulator. It takes less resistance to flow through many tall things because they conduct electricity much better then air. This is why a tall metal spike works well as a lightning rod. It provides a path of very little resistance so that the electricity will always go in that path.

Comment: Thanks very much for the explanation and the link.